# Expected Value Property

Tags: statistics

If I have two independent random variables X and Y, which are uniformly distributed over [0, 1]. And I have a function of these two variables Z = (X-Y)^2. Is it true that E(Z) = E(X^2) - E(XY) - E(Y^2)?
Is there a simpler way of finding E(Z)?

Comment: Correcting for the algebra, it is also worth noting that independence implies $E[XY]=E[X]\times E[Y]$.

Comment: Thanks again! How does this translate to the variance of Z?

Comment: Again, variances of independent variables add.

Comment: V(X^2) - 2 V(X) V(Y) + V(Y^2)?

Comment: Variances add but they don't multiply.  Not even for independent variables.  [here](http://www.odelama.com/data-analysis/Commonly-Used-Math-Formulas/) is a convenient list of some the standard formulas used in computing expectation and variance.

Comment: Thank you! To my understanding, the middle portion should be 2 V(XY) and that evaluates to something that is in the link you showed. How about V(X^2) and V(Y^2) are those two correct? How should I go about evaluating these?

Comment: Really, go study those formulas.  You are looking for short cuts and it's not a good idea.  It should, for example, be very clear to you that Var$(2XY)\neq 2$Var$(XY)$.  Variances scale quadratically.  And that link will show you how to get things like Var$(X^2)$.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I took a deep breath and looked at it again and it makes sense. Thank you so much. Do you have any recommendations on how I can improve my knowledge of statistics? I find I am pretty rusty and don't have a good base.

Comment: I think any of the standard texts should do the job.  Or MIT (and probably other schools) offer online courses (free, I believe) which should cover the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(X-Y)^{2}=X^{2}-2XY+Y^{2}$ and expectation is linear so $EZ=E(X-Y)^{2}=EX^{2}-2EXY+EY^{2}$.  The formula you have written is wrong.

Comment: Right, I expanded wrong. Thanks!